Creating a self message results in errror
I am attempting to create a self-message in my sequence diagram using the following:
obj=Lifeline A~a

a->a

This results in the following error:
The duration of a self-message must be greater than 0, but was 0.

If I remove "a->a", there are no errors and the image is rendered.
I am using Umlet 15.1 on a Mac.
Any suggestions on how to specify the duration is most appreciated.
